# Is it possible to load an endpoint agent in my Heroku environment? ie: Carbon Black, Crowdstrike, etc

Tags: end-points

Can an endpoint security solution be loaded onto a Heroku instance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what can or cannot be installed in a certain technology is a question for the technology admins and is not a security question.

Answer (score 2):

Such endpoint agents require access (and typically root access) to be able to run. As Heroku is just a PaaS for deploying your code, you do not control the environment that code runs in. As such, you will ***not*** be able to load an endpoint agent into your Heroku environment.

What you *can* do for more control and monitoring, is to implement and/or improve the logging of the application you deploy in Heroku.